# Grafana cell inspect button flickers and cannot be used

Tags: grafana, panel, json-api

Grafana version 10.1.5 using Table panel with JSON API data source (marcusolsson-json-datasource) 10.1.5.

Occasionally, some of the cell inspect "eyeball" buttons will start a flashing animation and cannot be clicked. A refresh of the page sometimes fixes it, sometimes it doesn't.

We expect the icon to remain a static image and open the inspection pop-up window to show the contents of the respective cell. We have tried refreshing the page and the query which inconsistently fixes the issue.

[Inspect button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX6Wt.png)